# How to use slots with the class of ctypes.Strcuture in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing an application with Python 2.7 that export lots of 3D mesh structures from one application to the other one.

Because of the tons of 3D data, I define a class named 'Face' shown as following code as the temp data sturcture which is passed into c-dll.

My question: if I want to save memeory with slots, how can I re-define this class? Or is there any other way could save memeory efficiently?

```py
    class Face(ctypes.Structure):
        __slots__ = ()
        # __slots__ = ['A','B','C','vert_index','vert_index','edge_sm','sm_group','is_hidden','edge_hidden','mtl_index','uv']
        _fields_ = [
            ("A",               ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
            ("B",               ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
            ("C",               ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
            ("vert_index",      ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
            ("edge_sm",         ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_bool)),
            ("sm_group",        ctypes.c_int),
            ("is_hidden",       ctypes.c_bool),
            ("edge_hidden",     ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
            ("mtl_index",       ctypes.c_int),
            ("uv",              ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
        ]
```

Appreciate for any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: When I tried adding `__slots__` it just worked out-of-the-box. Did it not for you?